SqlAlchemy 2 foreign_keys and _user_defined_foreign_keys attributes not found on relationship property
I am getting AttributeError: _user_defined_foreign_keys on relationship fields in my versioned table.
Table one is a type table:
class Base(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class NotificationType(Base, Versioned)
    __tablename__ = "notification_types"
    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)

class Notification(Base)
    __tablename__ = "notification"
    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, primary_key=True)
    ...
    notification_type_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("event_types.id"), nullable=False, index=True)
    notification_relationship: Mapped["NotificationType"] = relationship(
        NotificationType, back_populates="NotificationType", foreign_keys=["notification_type_id"], lazy="joined", innerjoin=True
    )

In my Versioned mixin definition  (for history tables) I have mostly followed the code listed here.
I am also looping over the relationship attributes in order to try to carry over the notification type and relationship information:
def _history_mapper(local_mapper):
    if not super_mapper or local_mapper.local_table is not super_mapper.local_table:
        ...
        for prop in local_mapper.iterate_properties:
            if isinstance(prop, RelationshipProperty):
                columns = [fk.key for fk in prop._user_defined_foreign_keys]
        ...

I notice that when attempting to run this code, building fails on line columns = [fk.key for fk in prop._user_defined_foreign_keys] as _user_defined_foreign_keys is undefined. It will sometimes work if I debug and wait some amount of time at that line, otherwise I will get an attribute error:
    def _fallback_getattr(self, key):
        raise AttributeError(key)
->
    E   AttributeError: _user_defined_foreign_keys

I do not see any relevant documentation about why foreign_keys and _user_defined_foreign_keys attributes being lazy loaded during build or being awaitable. Is this because the Base class extends AsyncAttrs and needs to be awaited? Or am I doing something else wrong?
I am using SQLAlchemy = {version = "2.0.28", extras = ["asyncio"]}
